# Bash script for Gitlab CI

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I have a bash script that will look into the list of jobs running on the pipeline and search for 2 specific jobs.
If job A is a match, I want to run one part of the script that in some conditions will retry job B, if job B is found, do another part of the script that will retry job A.
In the solution I have now I do the search before I have the if statements, and that means both if conditions are met and the hole script will run. I don't know how to change my condition to avoid that... I am stuck so any suggestion would be awesome.
Here is a sketch of the script:

```
keyWord_A="jobA"
keyword_B="jobB"

# get the job_list with curl command
# search the job_list with jq for 
#            keyWord_A and store the result in match_A 
#            keyword_B and store the result in match_B

if [[ keyWord_A == match_A ]] ; then
#   run this code

if [[ keyWord_B == match_B ]] ; then
#   run this code
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more information on your overall use case? Maybe there is a better solution using gitlab-ci more conventionally. Tip: Make two scripts. One looking for B and retry A. One looking for A and retry B. If both scripts work independently proceed with a good definition of exit conditions (to avoid infinite loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I thought... I can get from the CI the name of the curent job. This way, I can use the name of the current job in my if conditions and get the desired output from the script:

```
keyWord_A="jobA"
keyword_B="jobB"

if [[ keyWord_A == CI_job ]] ; then
#   run this code

if [[ keyWord_B == CI_job ]] ; then
#   run this code
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know if both job A and B are found, you can add conditions to your test, or use a simple `else if` in order to execute one, or the others, but not both:

```bash
if [[ keyWord_A == match_A ]] ; then
#   run this code

elif [[ keyWord_B == match_B ]] ; then
#   run this code
fi
```

Here, if both conditions are met, only the first if will be executed. Not both.

Comment: Thanks VonC. Your solution with if... else will work for jobA. But when I'll want jobB to be executed, it won't go on the else branch, because the if condition will be met... Maybe if I change the second if so that it has an aditional condition... Something like if [[ keyWord_B == match_B and jobA_status != "running" ]] ; then
#   run this code

Comment: @Maria Do you want jobB to be executed when *both* condition are met? What about jobA in that case?

Comment: I want the script to go on the second if or on the elif branch when jobB is triggering the script.

Comment: @Maria Then you can reverse the order of ifs: when both A and B are met, only B (the now first if) will be executed.